# Android IllegalAccessError java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.toHours

Tags: java, android

Why would this:

```
long diffInMis = date2.getTime() - date.getTime();
diffInHour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffInMis);
```

throw this:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.toHours:(Z)V

?

I have that error in the developer console and cannot reproduce it.
By know i just do the math on my own, but I am curious.

Device: HTC Legend Android 2.2

Answer: TimeUnit missing in API < 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 5 didn't have [toHours](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html), but [Java 6 does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toHours%28long%29). My guess is you're using a version of the TimeUnit class at runtime that doesn't include toHours. This kind of exception occurs when your code cannot access the field or method from the location of your reference.

Comment: I tested it on the exported package on 3 devices and it worked.

Comment: it depends entirely on your runtime JVM.

Comment: [TimeUnit](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) now i got it, its missing in API < 9. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.